# Filter on nested (recursive) data ( Vue 2 )

Tags: vue.js, filter, nested, lodash, children

Here is an example of my JSON data :

```
"data":[  
  {  
     "id":01,
     "name":"test",
     "parent_id":null,
     "children":[  
        {  
           "id":15,
           "name":"subChild",
           "parent_id":21,
           "children":[  
              {  
                 "id":148,
                 "name":"subSubChild",
                 "parent_id":22,
                 "children":[  
                        ....
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  },
```

I would like to filter this level by level. I have made this method :

```
computed: {
      filteredData: function () {
        let filterData = this.filter.toLowerCase()
        return _.pickBy(this.data, (value, key) => {
          return _.startsWith(value.name.toLowerCase(), filterData)
        })
      },
```

This work for only the first "level" and I tried several solutions but none worked for children.

So, I would like to be able to filter by several levels.

If you have an idea! 
Thank you

Comment: What's the expected output? The objects which have `filterData` as `name`?

Comment: Yes. For more details: 
- category 1
     - subCategory 1-1
- category 2
     - subCategory 2-1
     - subCategory 2-2
- category 3
 .....

If I use the filter for "subCategory 2-2", i would like to see only "subCategory 2-2" and the parent "Category 2".

I hope I made myself understood ! 

Thanks you

Comment: @Lolo Does my answer below make sense? Let me know if I missed anything so we can work it out.

Comment: @jom of course! I answered you just below! Thanks again !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive function could come in handy for this particular purpose.

Try the following approach, and for better view, click on `Full page` link next to the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button down below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      filter: '',
      maintainStructure: false,
      data: [{
        "id": 01,
        "name": "test",
        "parent_id": null,
        "children": [{
          "id": 15,
          "name": "subChild",
          "parent_id": 21,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 148,
              "name": "subSubChild",
              "parent_id": 22,
              "children": []
            }, 
            {
              "id": 150,
              "name": "subSubChild3",
              "parent_id": 24,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }]
      }]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    $_find(items, predicate) {
      let matches = [];

      for (let item of items) {
        if (predicate(item)) {
          matches.push(item);
        } 
        else if (item.children.length) {
          let subMatches = this.$_find(item.children, predicate);
          
          if (subMatches.length) {
            if (this.maintainStructure) {
              matches.push({
                ...item,
                children: subMatches
              });
            }
            else {
              matches.push(subMatches);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      return matches;
    },

    filterBy(item) {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.filter.toLowerCase());
    }
  },

  computed: {
    filteredData() {
      return this.$_find(this.data, this.filterBy);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>Filter by <code>item.name</code>:</label>
    <input v-model.trim="filter" placeholder="e.g. subsub" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="maintainStructure" /> Maintain structure
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <hr />
  
  <pre>{{filteredData}}</pre>
</div>
```

Note that I'm prefixing the function with `$_` to sort of mark it as *private* function (as recommended in [this Style Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Private-property-names-essential)) since we're not going to invoke it anywhere else.

Comment: Hello, really thank you for your help ! I was stuck for a few days.. and this works. Have a good day!

Comment: @Lolo No problem. Glad we sorted it out. :)